# display one @section once in @foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, sections

Hi I'm new to laravel and can't understand `sections` very well, but I am trying to display a specific one in a loop only once and then repeat everything else, if a certain condition is true. Here is the code I'm trying to modify. Here i commented the line which i want only one time.

```
 @foreach ($pageTypes['news-events']->categories as $cat)
    <?php  $related = $page->relatedPages($pageTypes['news-events']->id, $cat->id); ?>
    @if ($related->count() > 0) 
        @section('tab-titles')
        //i want to display this LI once if true  
        <li class="tab first"><a href="#news" title="insight">Insight</a></li>
        @append
        @section('news-content')
            <div id="news" class="tabs_text">
                <h2>{{ strtoupper($cat->name) }} 
                </h2>
                <ul>
                @foreach($related as $news)
                    <li><a href="{{ url($news->url) }}" title="{{ $news->title }}">
                            {{ $news->title }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @append
    @endif
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an else since you only want to display it once

Check documentation here [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#if-statements)

```
@if ($related->count() > 0)
    @section('news-content')
        <div id="news" class="tabs_text">
            <h2>{{ strtoupper($cat->name) }} 
            </h2>
            <ul>
            @foreach($related as $news)
                <li><a href="{{ url($news->url) }}" title="{{ $news->title }}">
                        {{ $news->title }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @append
@else
    @section('tab-titles')
    //i want to display this LI once if true  
    <li class="tab first"><a href="#news" title="insight">Insight</a></li>
    @append
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one simple variable to put a check if a section is been displayed before or not.

```
 $check = 0; 
@foreach ($pageTypes['news-events']->categories as $cat)
        <?php  $related = $page->relatedPages($pageTypes['news-events']->id, $cat->id); ?>

        @if ($related->count() > 0)


          if($check==0)
    {
            @section('tab-titles')
    //i want to display this LI once if true  
      <li class="tab first"><a href="#news" title="insight">Insight</a></li>
            @append
    $check++;
    }
            @section('news-content')
                <div id="news" class="tabs_text">
                    <h2>{{ strtoupper($cat->name) }} 
                    </h2>
                    <ul>
                    @foreach($related as $news)
                        <li><a href="{{ url($news->url) }}" title="{{ $news->title }}">
                                {{ $news->title }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @append
        @endif
      @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know it is the most elegant solution or not. But you can achieve what you want as follows:

```
<?php $repeat = true; // first initialize as true ?>
@foreach ($pageTypes['news-events']->categories as $cat)
  <?php  $related = $page->relatedPages($pageTypes['news-events']->id, $cat->id); 

?>

    @if ($related->count() > 0)
       @if($your_certain_condition == true && $repeat)
        <?php $repeat = false; ?>
        @section('tab-titles')
         <li class="tab first"><a href="#news" title="insight">Insight</a></li>
        @append
      @endif 

        @section('news-content')
            <div id="news" class="tabs_text">
                <h2>{{ strtoupper($cat->name) }} 
                </h2>
                <ul>
                @foreach($related as $news)
                    <li><a href="{{ url($news->url) }}" title="{{ $news->title }}">
                            {{ $news->title }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @append
    @endif
  @endforeach
```